# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$new_qgs_layer' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$new_qgs_layer' (T_VARIABLE)

And I don't understand why. When I start the function I defined the variable `$new_qgs_layer` to `null` and I use it to stock the return of `str_replace` function.

My PHP code :

```php
public function makeLayer () {
    $current_session = $request->session()->get('key');

    $value[] = "3";
    $value[]= Imput::get('component');
    $value[] = "flux_balance";

    $search[] = "ID_SCENARIO";
    $search[] = "ID_COMPONENT";
    $search[] = "MYVARIABLE";

    $qgs_layer = file_get_contents("carbone_test.qgs");
    $new_qgs_layer = null;

    if ($qgs_layer === false) {
        return null;
    }
    $file_name = $current_session + "_layer"
    $new_qgs_layer = str_replace($search, $value, $qgs_layer);
    file_put_contents($file_name, $qgs_layer_new);

    return Response::json($file_name,200);
}
```

Comment: Missing semicolon at line   $file_name = $current_session + "_layer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T_VARIABLE` usually occurs when you miss the semi-colon where it is required. In your function, you have missed the `;` after this line.

```
$file_name = $current_session + "_layer";
```